# Is it possible to achieve Sitecore item version?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I want to archive Sitecore item version and not the entire item using Powershell script.

I could not find the way to archive version, articles are there to archive item but not the specific version. Also could not find the command in PowerShell documentation. https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/

I tried `ArchiveItem($item)` but it archives the entire item and not the version alone.

Can some one guide me to find the solution on this query?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible through `Sitecore Powershell` script. Write your logic like this.

```
# get item to archive and provide the version. Examle 3

$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -Uri "sitecore://master/{6151ACBE-40C3-45D5-BCE8-5E939C461C12}?lang=en&ver=3"

[Sitecore.Data.Archiving.ArchiveManager]::GetArchives($item.Database)

$archive = [Sitecore.Data.Archiving.ArchiveManager]::GetArchive("archive", $item.Database)

$archive.ArchiveVersion($item)

$archive.GetEntries(0,10)
```

Now when you go to the Archive window, you will see the version you have archived.

[image]

Comment: Would be better to add this answer to the existing question and this question be closed.

Comment: @MichaelWest Can you please share the link of the existing question ?

Comment: @kapil Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes Sumit, This solve my problem. Thanks